# backend utilization - google cloud platform load balancer - 500%

Tags: google-cloud-load-balancer

Good morning everybody, i got an issue this morning in my company web load balancer.
we have a google loadbalancer linked with 2 instance that are 2 pfsense where we configure our webservers.
this morning happend that in loadbalancer - backend - backend details the backend load/utilization was 500% and consequently all of my webserver was not viewable by customers.
CPU load and memory were ok and i cannot see any issues, has such a thing ever happened to anyone?
best regards,

Comment: have you got a solution? Seems I am facing the same problem.